# How to mimic the set - hashset relation

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

In Java, the `HashSet` is an implementation of the `Set` interface which allows us to do this:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
```

So if I create an interface `IFruit` and some implementations as follows

```
public interface IFruit {
    public String getColour();
    /* more methods */
}
```

```java
public class Apple implements IFruit {
    public String getColour() {
        return "red";
    }
}
```

```java
public class Banana implements IFruit {
    public String getColour() {
        return "yellow";
    }
}
```

then why can't I do this?

```
IFruit apple1 = new Apple()
```

I am using eclipse. The interface and the two classes are also different class files in the same package. I am trying to use them in another class in a different package in the same project. It gives a compilation error when I try to instantiate it like this:

```
public class InterfaceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IFruit newFruit = new Apple();
    }
}
```

But oddly, if I put everything in a single file it works!

Comment: *Apple which implements Apple* - What??

Comment: you CAN do this, probably you are doing wrong something else :). Post your code.

Comment: `public class Apple implements IFruit`

Comment: *Apple which implements Apple* - do you mean 'which implements `IFruit`'?

Comment: The compiler is very stupid (in human understanding) and cannot read your mind ;-) You have tell him that an apple is a fruit!

Comment: [... another class say Apple which implements Apple] You cannot implement a class, only interfaces can be implemented, classes can be extended though.

Comment: Make sure you have imported `Apple` and `IFruit` in the class `InterfaceTest`, In eclipse you can organize the imports with `Ctrl+Shift+o`.

Comment: Sorry man, useless question.
I thought I would see Apple and Banana in the ctrl + space popup.
Just an import issue.
I am literally kicking myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler isn't very smart. What if you passed in a `Car` object? Or a list? Are those fruits?

Change the declaration `public class Apple{` to:

```
public class Apple implements IFruit {
```

Edit: Make sure you import `IFruit` and `Apple`.

Comment: Totally my fault, I didn't mention anything about it. The apple class is implementing it.